# IF else & else if in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

please check my script.

```
  if($namachief != NULL)
        {
            echo $namachief;
        }
  else if ($namarm != NULL)
        {
           echo $namarm;
        }
   else
        {
            echo "Something wrong. Please contact US";
        }
```

My condition isn't working when in this condition => `$namarm != NULL`, I only get white page but its normal when  in this condition => `$namachief != NULL`.

It's fine when i do this
`echo $namachief;` & `echo $namarm;`

```
if () {

}
else if (){
}
else if(){
------------------------ My Script Here -----------------------------
}
```

Both answer below are right. My problem lies here. In my form I did this
`<option value="none">None</option>` Then i change it to                             `<option value="">None</option>`

Comment: try to use if(!empty($namachief)){ }

Comment: I did that and the result were same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your condition as below:-

```
if(isset($namachief)  &&  !empty($namachief)){
    echo $namachief;
}
else if (isset($namarm)  &&  !empty($namarm)){
    echo $namarm;
}
else{
    echo "Something wrong. Please contact US";
}
```

If you want to print both variables **if both are set and have valid values** then,

```
if(empty($namarm)  &&  empty($namachief)){
    echo "Something wrong. Please contact US";
}
else if (!empty($namachief)  &&  !empty($namarm)){
    echo $namarm;
    echo $namachief;
}
else if (isset($namarm)  &&  !empty($namarm)){
    echo $namarm;
}
else if(isset($namachief)  &&  !empty($namachief)){
     echo $namachief;
}
else{
  // else stuff
}
```

Comment: yeah, i making a mistake at my form

Answer (score 4):

You try like this

```
if($namachief != NULL || $namachief != "")
    {
        echo $namachief;
    }
else if ($namarm != NULL || $namarm != "")
    {
       echo $namarm;
    }
else
    {
        echo "Something wrong. Please contact US";
    }
```