# Condition Using Controller in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a function, it exists and does not exist in the search feature. Condition does not exist, will display Error 404. Condition, exists. Then it will display from search. But in the code I wrote, it only shows Error 404.

This is my model:

```
    function search_album($keyword){
    $result=$this->db->query("SELECT tbl_album.*,DATE_FORMAT(album_date,'%d %M %Y') AS date FROM tbl_album WHERE album_title LIKE '%$keyword%'");
    return $result;
}
```

This is my controller:

```
function search(){
    $keyword=str_replace("'", "", $this->input->post('xfilter',TRUE));
    $x['data']=$this->model_album->search_album($keyword);
    if(empty($x)  &&  empty($keyword)){
        $this->load->view('view_contents',$x);
    }
    else if (!empty($x)  &&  !empty($keyword)){
        $this->load->view('view_error_404');
    }
    
}
```

I've tried from this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716241/if-else-else-if-in-codeigniter), but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

**ONE:** You have interchanged your **if statements**. Like, if the search did not return any data and the keyword was not supplied, it is supposed to display the "**view_error_404**", otherwise, it is supposed to load data into the view "**view_contents**".You did the vice versa I have corrected that for you in the code below.

**TWO:** You are checking if **$x** is empty which will never be empty as you have initialized **$x['data']**. Note that the model can return empty data, such that **$x['data']** is empty. Instead, check if the search result is empty by replacing **empty($x)** with **empty($x['data'])**

**THREE:** In your model, you are returning the query builder class, but not the actual data from the query statement. instead, replace `return $result;` with  `return $result->result();`

**FOUR:**
From your **if statements**, you need to add an **else statement** so that if the 2 conditions are never met, it can execute. With your current implementation, there is a state which will not meet first or second conditions and will lead to a blank screen.

```
if(empty($x['data'])  &&  empty($keyword)){
     $this->load->view('view_error_404');
}else if (!empty($x['data'])  &&  !empty($keyword)){
    $this->load->view('view_contents',$x);    
}else{
    $this->load->view('view_error_404'); // replace this code with your preference
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much. You are very helpful in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention search function in routes.php file like this:-

```
$routes['search'] ='your_controller_name/search';
```

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your function `model_album->search_album($keyword)` and assuming it returns a string or array, you don't need to worry about checking for the keyword, since without a keyword the function should return false or empty.

anyway you mixed up your if/else conditions, since you are checking for not empty results to return a 404, instead of empty result returning the 404.

this should do it:

```
if(empty($x)){
    $this->load->view('view_error_404');
}
else {
    $this->load->view('view_contents',$x);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this one before, but it doesn't work. Thank you for your help

Comment: *it doesn't work*: what does not work? are you getting the 404 view, using above code? If so please read the 1st line of the answer *without knowing your function model_album->search_album($keyword) and assuming it returns a string or array*, please specify and eventually edit your Q.

Comment: Okay, thank you. By the way, I've updated my Q, is it understandable enough? I feel there is something wrong with writing the code that I made